# Xperia Z3v Simultaneous LTE and Voice Service

Tags: mobile-data, sony-xperia, 4g

I'm told by Verizon that the Z3v will be unable to access mobile data while in a call until January. If only they told you this *before* the sale! In any case, does anyone know of a workaround, or a way to get the software update early? I considered flashing something from Sony's developer world, but as I understand it this will impact camera functionality...

Any known way to get around this without waiting until Sony/Verizon push the update?

[image: Mobile data not available]
<sup>"Mobile data not available" (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I wonder how that should work without a second "receiver set" – as for calls, the device has to "drop back" to 3G. So if you want to use mobile data while in call, switching to 3G entirely seems to be the only valid option to me.

Comment: Spoke with a Verizon Rep today and he said they expect to have this fixed by April.

Answer (score 1):

I have been told that the Z3V will never be capable of simultaneous talk and Data by Verizon. Sony just confirmed that it isn't capable, but didn't say what the future holds. The Z3V was built with only one radio and was not built to support VoLTE. Verizon is posting replies on their Droid Turbo stating it will be getting it in a software update,  but they are not doing that on the Z3V. I am guessing that is because it doesn't support VoLTE and that is how they are rolling this out now (phones coming to market after Aug2014). However, let me know if you get a different response from Sony or Verizon, because I have been told the Z3V will never get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just got off the phone with Verizon and they confirmed the z3v will get the update to fix this problem 1st quarter next year